# Implementation of stack using vectors in c++

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stack

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Stack {

private:
    int maxSize;
    vector<int> v;
    int top;
public:
    Stack(int size) {
        this->maxSize = size;
        this->v.reserve(this->maxSize);
        this->top = -1;
    }

    void push(int j) {
        if (!(this->isFull())) {
            this->v[++this->top] = j;
        } else {
            cout << "stack is full"<<endl;
        }

    }

    int pop() {
        if (!(this->isEmpty())) {

            return this->v[this->top--];
        } else {
            cout << "\nstack is empty"<<endl;
            cout<<  "StackOverflow "<<endl;
        }
    }

    int peak() {
        return this->v[this->top];
    }
    bool isEmpty() {
        return (this->top == -1);
    }

    bool isFull() {
        return (this->top == this->maxSize - 1);
    }

};

int main() {

    Stack s(10);

    s.push(10);
    s.push(20);
    cout<<s.pop();
    cout<<"\n"<<s.pop();
    s.push(40);
    cout<<"\n"<<s.pop();

}
```

How can I make this code more better and reliable for these reasons:

- The output of this code is 20 10 40 .
- But in the output I want to print **"Stack is empty"** after every
  time the stack is empty after popping out all the elements from the
  stack
- It fails toprint **"Stackis Empty "** every time .

Comment: "How can I make this code more better" stop `using namespace std` first of all

Comment: Your `main` doesn't pop when stack is empty, you always pop when there's at least one element. BTW. why use `this` so much? It's not needed.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen after popping out all the element i want to print the message i.e..Stackis empty

Comment: Why not use `std::stack<int, std::vector<int>>` ? Or do you have some overriding need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: BTW, C++ is not Java.  You don't need `this->` to access member variables or methods.  Access them directly.

Answer (score 3):

You have UB in your code:

```
this->v[++this->top] = j;

 return this->v[this->top--];
```

ans so on. The fact that you reserved space in a `std::vector` does not make accessing thous elements legal, you access elements out of bounds. And you overcomplicated your code - `std::vector` maintains it's size so you do not need index `top` at all. All you need is `push_back()` adding element and use `back()` to access last and then `pop_back()` to remove it. You can use `std::vector>::empty()`or `std::vector::size()` to check if there are elements left.

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem in your code is due to your attempting out of bounds access with a `std::vector`; the behaviour of which is *undefined*. Note that `reserve` does not make that number of elements available for use; only *potentially* available without a subsequent memory reallocation. If you had used `at` rather than `[]` then your C++ standard library would have thrown a runtime error.

`std::vector` has `push_back` and a `pop_back` functions which does allow you to use it to model a stack reasonably effectively.

**But**, `typedef std::stack<int> Stack;` in place of all your code is by far the best way.

Don't use C++ standard library container objects to model other containers that are also in the C++ standard library. Container objects are *really difficult* to write properly; and take a lot of debugging.

Comment: Yeah. Let's not learn programming at all, somebody will eventually create a library for what you need.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: No, no, no! Just don't learn to program by writing containers. It's exhausting, and ultimately fruitless.

Comment: I think by "make this code more better" the OP meant "fix it for me pls tenku" rather than "make it less style-OCD-triggering"...

Comment: This is not an answer, but should be a comment. OP may have reasons to implement his own stack.

Comment: @Slava: No, comments are not for answers. This one is staying up as I intend it to be an answer. Remember that C++ *includes* the standard library.

Comment: Having something already implemented in standard library does not make attempt to write similar illegal. You may have an opinion that it is useless but place for opinions is in comments.

Comment: @Slava: Indeed, certainly not illegal in any sense of the word, including the correct sense. It's just plain pointless. What next, writing your own version of `std::shared_ptr`, or your own version of `std::numeric_limits`? Learn the syntax and library at the same time, pretty please with sugar on top. The fact that even at my old University the professors insist on asking students to write this sort of nonsense is a real gripe.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with implementing `std::shared_ptr` as an exercise.

Comment: There are cases where you write code to do something useful, where best practices are important. In those cases, I agree with your sentiment. But sometimes, you write code just to see if you can, just to see if it works, just to find out something. And in those cases, what you're expressing here doesn't really apply. And I feel like this question is the latter case. That's why I agree that this would make a useful comment but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Slava: I'd sooner hire someone who knows the syntax, knows the library, and has solved a real problem. At best, learning how to write containers only gets you the first of these three things.

Comment: Your tirade against such exercises, although justified, would be better directed at the educational establishment rather than fellow SO users...

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Indeed, I'm back at the University in October.

Comment: "I'd sooner hire someone who knows the syntax..." I respect your opinion but it's still not enough to make that an answer.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language, but still I do not think it asks of who you would hire or not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20988875)

Comment: @Slava help me about this problem

Comment: @mkaes: Very well, I've tweaked. Keep up the reviewing!

Answer (score 1):

The way you programmed it, it only prints "Stack is empty" if the stack is already empty when you call `pop`, not when it has 1 element and is only empty after calling `pop`.

Suppose you have 1 element on the stack. So `top` is 0.

```
int pop() {
    if (!(this->isEmpty())) {
```

This `if` evaluatetes to true, and therefore nothing will be printed. This is because `isEmpty()` evaluates to `false` with `top` set to 0.

What you want to do is doing the pop first, and *then* checking if the stack is empty. On top of checking it at the beginning either way, because you can't pop an empty stack.

Comment: You still need to check *before* popping because otherwise the stack pointer can exceed the boundary if `pop` is called again.

Comment: What I meant was checking whether `top` is set to `-1` or not to decide if it's empty. Sorry for being unclear. But yes, you're definitely right, there also needs to be a check at the beginning either way.